# For each node in XML not working as expected

Tags: xml, vb.net, foreach, nodes

I'm wanting to use a "For each" function to go through each existing node in my xml file using vb.net. It kind of works but not how I would like or expect.. for some reason I cant work out all the node inner texts are combined into one long string, which is displayed in the one message box. what I was expecting was a new message box for each tag with its inner text.

The xml file is quite basic (because i was still testing it) and is showen here below:

```
<DATA>
<TOM>123</TOM>
<DICK>ABC</DICK>
<HARRY>Hello</HARRY>
</DATA>
```

Where I am expecting three message boxes, one with "123" the second with "ABC" and the third with "Hello". I am provided with just the one message box saying "123ABCHello"...

The code I am using to display the message box is as follows:

```
Dim doc as new XmlDocument()
doc.load(C:\test.xml)

Dim Nodelist as XmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("DATA")
For Each Node as XmlElement In Nodelist
msgbox(Node.InnerText)
Next
```

Comment: Try `doc.SelectNodes("DATA/*")` instead of `doc.SelectNodes("DATA")`.

Comment: Well shoot me that works... what's the /* mean? I'm namely not a programmer just a self taught hobbiest

Comment: `DATA/*` just selects all elements that are children of the element `DATA`. Your `For Each` loop then selects every element of this collection (and then prints each `text()` value with `InnerText`)